# Debug QNX target using Ubuntu host and gdb

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, qnx, gdbserver

This is a question from an absolute beginner.

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 host, gdb 7.7.1 installed on it and a project cross-compiled for qnx. I also have a qnx target, that I want to debug my app on.

The instructions on the internet tell me to use either `gdb` on PC + `gdbserver`, but I don't have gdbserver installed and I don't think I can compile gdb for qnx. I have something called `pdebug`. Instructions for qnx tell me that gdb has to have the `target qnx` command, that it clearly does not posess.

Here's what I've done:

```
# Assuming that 255.255.255.255 is the target ip and 1234 is the port
# On target
pdebug 1234

On host
gdb
gdb> target remote 255.255.255.255:1234
```

Then I got a couple of warnings and the `gdb>` again, as it was normal.

I managed to install a connection between my host and target, but when I hit `run` in gdb, it tries to run my local copy of the app, instead of running it on target.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way one can debug qnx apps with Ubuntu's gdb.

You have to use qnx's `gdb` built for the exact this purpose, that is able to run `target qnx` and many other commands you will need. You have to use qnx's `gdb` on your host and `pdebug` on your target and run the same commands you ran:

```
# on target
pdebug 1234

# on host
ntoarm-gdb
(gdb) file MyQnxApp
(gdb) target qnx 255.255.255.255:1234
(gdb) upload MyQnxApp /mnt/myWorkingDir/MyQnxApp
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
```

Then you will see the info about your connection:

```
Remote debugging using 255.255.255.255:1234
Remote target is <your_endianness>
```

See this detailed [instructions](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/prog/using_gdb.html).

Comment: Could you please tell us what to do if the MyQnxApp is already present in the target? i.e. I do not want to upload the exe, rather just reference its location on the target

Comment: Is there no way to build gdb to support QNX?  Or can only QNX do it?  (I'm tired of using QNX's gdb 8.3 and want to upgrade :) )